# Load a image on top of another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 3 images inside a div.  How can I dynamically load and overlay a image on one of those three images that are in the div?

My HTML looks like this

```
<div id="div1">


    <img id="img1" src="images/Green.png" draggable="false" class="tile" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img id="img2" src="images/Green.png" draggable="false" class="tile" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img id="img3" src="images/Green.png" draggable="false" class="tile" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">


</div>

<div id="inner">
    <img id="dragRed" src="images/Red.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="5%" height="5%">
    <img id="dragYellow" src="images/Yellow.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="5%" height="5%">
    <img id="dragGreen" src="images/Green.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="5%" height="5%">
</div>
```

I tried using this script but it causes img1 to vanish.

```
$("#img1").each(function () {
                var $overlay = $('<div></div>');
                $overlay.css({
                    position: "relative",
                    display: "inline-block",
                    width: $(this).width(),
                    height: $(this).height(),
                    backgroundPosition: "center center",
                    backgroundImage: "url(images/affection.png)"
                });
                $(this).wrap($overlay);
            });
```

Comment: `$("#img1").each` will look for multiple elements with an `id` of `img1`. `Id`s must be unique. Since all of the images have a class of `tile`, you could start by changing that bit of code to read `$(".tile").each`

Comment: I actually only want to change img1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is: **you are trying to change the background of something that wraps the image.** The **background** will always be behind.

You need to include an element that lives together with the image and overlays it.
With some minor change, we wrap the images with `div`:

```
<div id="div1">
    <div id="img1">
       <img src="https://placekitten.com/g/50/50" draggable="false" class="tile" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    </div>
</div>
```

And the JS nows looks for `div` and appends a overlay next to the image:

```
$("#div1 div").each(function () {
  var $overlay = $('<div class="overlay"></div>');
  $overlay.css({
    position: "absolute",
    top: "0",
    left: "0",
    display: "inline-block",
    zIndex: "1",
    width: $(this).width(),
    height: $(this).height(),
    backgroundPosition: "center center",
    backgroundImage: "url(https://placehold.it/50x50)"
  });
  $(this).append($overlay);
});
```

Here is the [Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/pu2w6rgo/2/)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks that really helped.  Is there a way I can scale the image size to a percentage of the div size?  Instead of 100% like this-
                    width: $(this).width(),
                    height: $(this).height(),

Comment: You could use the `$.css` with the css transform property: https://jsfiddle.net/pu2w6rgo/3/